# Touchscreen's X axis is inverted on my tablet

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, touchscreen, hid

Touchscreen's X axis is inverted.
If I touch right bottom corner, tablet thinks I clicked windows button in left bottom corner.

This happened after installing driver from the internet (before it was unknown device)

Device is now "Goodix Touch HID"
I found this driver by searching VEN_GDIX&DEV_1001 (device ID or something, I have Windows in another language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I repaired it.
It, of course, was a driver problem.

In driver installer's directory, there was TouchSetting.gt file with following content:

```
(...)
[Support]
ESD=1
;SensorID=0
GtpTool=0
X2X=0
Y2Y=0
X2Y=0
Log=0
(...)
```

Apparently:
**`X2X`** means **X axis is inverted**
**`Y2Y`** means **Y axis is inverted** and
**`X2Y`** means **X and Y axes are swapped**

So only thing I had to do was to change

```
X2X=0
```

to

```
X2X=1
```

Then reinstall the driver and I solved my problem.