# Touchscreen's X axis and Y axis is inverted on my tablet win 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchscreen, hid

I have 11 tablets, all have the same windows version

but only in one of the x-axis  and the y-axis are inverted for some reason

and I already viewed [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1172155/touchscreens-x-axis-is-inverted-on-my-tablet#answer-1176298)

So i checked my problematic tablet against some other tablets all have the same TouchSetting.gt configuration file

My driver is HID-compliant touch screen("Goodix Touch HID" )- trying to update the driver did not yield any result.

The only solution that i have for now is to set:

```
[Support]
ESD=1       ;Driver supports ESD recovery processing
;SensorID=0 ;According to the different SensorID send different configuration
GtpTool=0   ;GuitarTestPlateform tool support
X2X=0 //change this to 1
Y2Y=0 //change this to 1
```

but I don't want to this, is there any way to find the source of the problem?

Comment: Did you try running the touchscreen calibration?

Comment: yes, and I also tried to restore from an image that i have