# Touchscreen only works after restart Windows 11 Goodix HID Driver Version 1.2.2.26

Tags: windows, windows-11, touchscreen, tablet, windows-tabletpc

I have a tablet running Windows 11 pro. The screen does not respond to touch when the system first boots up. But, the touchscreen would work after a restart (not shutdown and reboot). Once the tablet wakes up from either sleep or hibernation, the screen becomes unresponsive to touch again. A restart (not shutdown and reboot) would restore the touchscreen functionality.

It has a goodix touch input.

I followed this post earlier and was able to fix the inverted touch.

[Touchscreen's X axis is inverted on my tablet](https://superuser.com/questions/1172155/touchscreens-x-axis-is-inverted-on-my-tablet)

I was also able to fix the issue where the touch screen wont work after sleep. so I changed SleepDisable=0 to SleepDisable=1.

This is what my TouchSetting.gt looks like now,

```
    [Setting]
;UpdateCFG=0
SendCFG=1       ;Send CFG to touch IC when loading driver   
SleepDisable=1
PhysicalXsize=3072  ;Physical size£¬the unit is 0.1mm
PhysicalYsize=1800

[Support]
ESD=1       ;Driver supports ESD recovery processing
;SensorID=0 ;According to the different SensorID send different configuration
GtpTool=0   ;GuitarTestPlateform tool support
X2X=0
Y2Y=1
X2Y=0
Log=0
Flashless=0
ICType=GT910
PrtScreen=0
CtrlAltDel=0
HomeKeyTouchTime=3
VolumeKeyEnable=0
FingerFirst=0
PenAsFinger=0
resetRevert=0

[Feature]
Pen=0       ;stylus/pen support
NumberOfKey=1   ;The total number of keys supported,equal to 0 does not support key
Key1=0xe3   ;0xe3 is home key,Must be a hexadecimal number
Key2=
Key3=
Key4=

[CFG]
DefaultCFG=0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x10,0x0A,0x35,0x00,0x01,0x08,0x28,0x08,0x50,0x32,0x03,0x05,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x18,0x1A,0x1E,0x14,0x90,0x30,0xAA,0x3D,0x3F,0x31,0x0D,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x11,0x18,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2C,0x56,0x94,0xC5,0x02,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x98,0x2F,0x00,0x8C,0x35,0x00,0x7F,0x3D,0x00,0x76,0x46,0x00,0x6E,0x50,0x00,0x6E,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0C,0x0D,0x0E,0x0F,0x10,0x11,0x14,0x15,0x16,0x17,0x18,0x19,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x04,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x0A,0x0C,0x0D,0x0E,0x0F,0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x19,0x1B,0x1C,0x1E,0x1F,0x20,0x21,0x22,0x23,0x24,0x25,0x26,0x27,0x28,0x29,0x2A,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x16,0x01
senserid_0=
senserid_1=
senserid_2=
senserid_3=
senserid_4=
senserid_5=
```

[this is the goodix touch HID properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSr7L.png)

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the driver and also tried different driver version as well. My laptop is a Toshiba Hybrid2016cd

[laptop specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd2BZ.png)

I have disabled fastboot and also tried updating driver from

https://www.driveridentifier.com/scan/goodix-touch-hid-driver/download/896997633/BF93813F447241D3A9648A36BC08DCA2/ACPI%5CGDIX1001

But the touch stops working if I update the driver, I have also reinstalled windows but that didn't work as well.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add hardware specifications (make/model, etc.). Of note, Goodix made dozens of devices already.

Comment: Your driver is out of date. You should update it. [Here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=fa654b95-e56e-43bb-a7cb-10fe6712bbd2) is the driver from Microsoft. If it doesn’t work then we need the device id

Comment: @Ramhound I tried updating driver from driverupdater[.]com using this link https://www.driveridentifier.com/scan/desktop.php?scanid=BF93813F447241D3A9648A36BC08DCA2

Comment: @Ramhound and this link https://www.driveridentifier.com/scan/goodix-touch-hid-driver/download/896997633/BF93813F447241D3A9648A36BC08DCA2/ACPI%5CGDIX1001

But.it doesn't work, I also have disabled fastboot

Comment: Forget about the files you found. Did you try the file that I provided directly from Microsoft? The hardware id is `acpi\gdix1002`?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to update it just now and it says,

https://imgur.com/a/i7BqnXO

Comment: @Ramhound I pressed yes and installed the driver but the touch stooped working. Then i uninstalled the driver and installed the old driver 1.2.2.26 and touch started working again after a restart. but the problem continues, and touch doesn't work when i turn on after shutting down.

Comment: Which is the reason I requested the hardware id of your hardware

Comment: this is the device ID, https://imgur.com/a/xRUdnmH

Comment: @Ramhound this is my device id ACPI\GDIX1001

Comment: Do not, under any circumstance, ever, download and install drivers from "Identifier" sites. Drivers should only be downloaded and installed from trusted publishing locations, such as the brand site, or a good source such as Microsoft's Windows Update catalog.

Comment: @lemmy - It's not shocking the a driver for `acpi\gdix1002` doesn't work with `acpi\gdix1001` which is the reason I asked for the identifier when I provide the driver from the update catalog. If information is not in the question body, that is needed to answer the question, then it should be added to the body of the question

Comment: [Here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=gdix1001) is the correct set of drivers that support `acpi\gdix1001` instead of `acpi\gdix1002 `

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you so much for your help, i tried all versions and the touchsetting.gt doesnt work on them and the touch is inverted but the driver version Shenzhen Huiding Technology Co.,Ltd. - HIDClass - 11/18/2016 12:00:00 AM - 1.3.2.1103 works perfectly ,thank you so much